# Работа с селектом

Tags: php, html

Есть некий селект. Вот код :

```
<select name="test">
  <option value="1">one</one>
  <option value="2">two</one>
</select>
```

Нужно, чтобы при перезагрузке сохранялся выбор пользователя, учитывая, что этот выбор сохраняется в базе данных. К примеру пользователь выбрал two. Это фиксируеться в базе даных. Как организовать что бы при перезагрузке страницы, и даже после выключения браузера и нового включения, был выбран (или назначен selected) option two

Comment: @Sergalas, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранять значение можно во многих местах - параметры к странице, куки, хранилища, локальная БД, etc.
А выбирать с помощью JS можно так: `<option value='2' selected>Two</option>` (назначать метку `selected` можно или на стороне сервера как-то так: `pring "<option value='2' " . ifIssetLabel() ? "selected" : "" . >Two</option>"`).

Answer (score 0):

При выборе селекта с помощью Ajax запускайте скрипт, посылающий запрос к бд на сохранение данных. При перезагрузке страницы вытягивайте данные из бд и отмечайте нужный пункт в списке.

Comment: как отмечать этот нужный пункт вот в чем и вопрос.

Comment: <option value="1" selected>